# Room delete inverted selection

Tags: android, android-room

I have a pretty large database and users have an ability to select entities via GUI. There is a button to select all entities. After it has been pressed it selects all entities, and clicking at the entity adds it into a list which excludes it from all. I need a DAO method that will delete all entities excluding entities on the list. So I need something like:

```
@Query("DELETE FROM Entity WHERE id != :entities.id")
fun deleteExcluding(entities: List<Entity>)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot pass `entities` as `List<Entity>` ...
but have to pass them as `List<Integer>`, `List<String>`  or `String[]`:

```
@Query("DELETE FROM Entity WHERE id NOT IN (:entities)")
fun deleteAllExcept(entities: List<Integer>)
```